# Create a view with changing table names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have a set of tables that have a day of week suffix (Table_Mon, Table_Tue, etc.).  I am trying to come up with a design where an application can pull a limited set of data out of these columns for whatever day it is currently.  I was looking at using dynamic sql in a view but that is not an option.  What is the correct solution so that an application can query the tables without needing to provide the day of week?

Comment: You will need to use dynamic sql, but instead of a view you should use a Stored Procedure.

Comment: I'm tempted to ask why Table_Mon, Table_Tue and so on exist... they're not just views on a master table are they? Is there data in the tables that actually identifies it - a date column perhaps? If so perhaps UNION them all together and apply a condition on the identifying column.

Comment: If the application isn't providing a day of the week, how will your dynamic anything know which table to query?

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 These are snapshots of data from a vendor system so that changes can be seen and reported day by day.

Comment: @EricBrandt The application only cares about data 'today'.  That is why I was looking to create a view that abstracts away the day of week.

Comment: @SDH Are you in control of the import process? If you loaded it into a single table, it would be trivial to make a view for what you want.

Comment: The root of your struggles if right here "We have a set of tables that have a day of week suffix". That sounds like it should be a column in a single table instead of 7 distinct tables all with the same structure.

Answer (score 2):

It is a poorly designed database schema. Ideally, there should be only one table with a column `Week_Day` and you should be able to query that table by just adding the appropriate `WHERE` clause.

Anyway, you will need to use dynamic sql, but instead of a view you should use a Stored Procedure. Something like...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Get_Data
AS
BEGIN 
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE  @Sql       NVARCHAR(MAX)
            ,@TableName SYSNAME; 

    SET @TableName = N'TABLE_' + LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) , 3);

    SET @Sql = N' SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)

    Exec sp_executesql @Sql

END
```

Comment: "Need to use dynamic sql" is a bit of a stretch. Could easily make if statements that run different selects based on the date. :)

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean but doing that can result in really horrible performance. If that approach was taken you would need the main procedure and a different procedure for each of the paths.

Comment: @SeanLange it can only if it uses a bad execution plan, but you could either break it out as you suggest or option recompile which doesn't seem too different than what this answer would do.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean or even optimize for unknown. ;) The best solution by far would be to fix the schema.

Comment: @SeanLange Agreed. :)

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean responding to your comment "option recompile which doesn't seem too different than what this answer would do", I am afraid your assumption is wrong, `sp_executesql` will benefit from caching paramterised execution plan, it is not the same as using option recompile, actually it is quite the opposite.